# What SQL Server edition supports CDC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

Does any one know which SQL Server 2014/2016 edition/version, supports CDC (Change Data Capture)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change Data Capture is supported in the Developer and Enterprise Editions of SQL Server up to and including SQL Server 2016 RTM.

SQL Server from 2016 with Service Pack 1 and higher also supports CDC in Standard Edition.

Source: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions

Answer (score 5):

Change Data Capture is supported in Standard Edition since [SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016).
It's still unsupported in Web and Express editions.