# How to model/query this data problem? Is this a timeseries issue?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, temporal-tables

We have a large amount of data in a MS-SQL2014 (v12) server.

We need to determine if a product was for sale in some time period.

For example, was this inventory for sale in the month of July 2022? (1st-Jul-2022 -> 31st-Jul-2022).

I've made a [db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iE0U2LZy) which can be used to refine the answer(s).

The data we have is some inventory/stock list. It's a list of events that occur to single inventory items. So here's a sample of some 'events' that happen to this one random widget, in the inventory:

```
Sample Data - Events that occur with some inventory
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

| Id | Name      | Date       | Price | Status    |
| -- | --------- | -----------| ----- | --------- |
| 1  | INV-1     | 2022-05-01 | 100   | Available | New
| 1  | INV-1 aaa | 2022-09-05 | 100   | Available | Name change
| 1  | INV-1 bbb | 2022-09-06 | 100   | Available | Name change
| 1  | INV-1     | 2022-09-07 | 120   | Available | Name and price change
| 1  | INV-1     | 2022-09-08 | 120   | Sold      | Sold
| 1  | INV-1     | 2022-10-02 | 120   | Available | Returned. Back for sale
| 1  | INV-1     | 2022-10-01 | 115   | Available | Price change
| 1  | INV-1     | 2022-10-01 | 115   | Sold      | New

| 2  | INV-2     | 2022-05-01 | 200   | Available | New (Other product)
| 3  | INV-3     | 2022-05-01 | 300   | Available | New (Other product)
| 4  | INV-4     | 2022-10-01 | 400   | Available | New (Other product)
| 5  | INV-5     | 2022-10-01 | 500   | Available | New (Other product)
```

```
Expected Results:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

-- Which products were available in JULY?
| Id |
| -- |
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |

-- Which products available in OCT?
| Id |
| -- |
| 1  | -- Was returned and put back to available again.
| 2  |
| 3  |
| 4  |
| 5  |
```

Is this possible?

At first, I was told to investigate TEMPORAL TABLES. That sounds like it might seriously help .. except that it's for MS-SQL2016 (v13+). I'm on v12 -and- I won't be able to upgrade or migrate the data to a v13+ version. Also, I'm not on an Enterprise Edition and can't go to that.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: @ErikDarling tried to clean up the OP with suggestions from your link

Answer (score 1):

Feature availability aside, please keep in mind SQL Server 2014 is officially [no longer a supported version of the product line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/sql-server-2014) by Microsoft, and will stop receiving even security updates in roughly 1.5 years, so you should probably plan to upgrade soon.

---

A similar feature to Temporal Tables that is available in SQL Server 2014 is [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Change data capture (CDC) uses the SQL Server agent to record insert, update, and delete activity that applies to a table. This makes the details of the changes available in an easily consumed relational format. Column information and the metadata that is required to apply the changes to a target environment is captured for the modified rows and stored in change tables that mirror the column structure of the tracked source tables. Table-valued functions are provided to allow systematic access to the change data by consumers.

It's a fairly common feature, that's been around a while, for keeping track of historical changes to the data. So it's a reliable feature to use, but it also has some limitations / things to consider:

1. Certain schema changes such as adding / removing columns or changing a columns data type aren't automatically propagated to the history tables. To workaround this, you need to remove Change Data Capture, manually apply the change, and re-add Change Data Capture - loosely speaking.
2. The base tables being tracked can't use clustered columnstore indexes.
3. Any computed columns on the base tables are stored as NULL values in the history tables.
4. The history tables don't directly store the timestamp of when the change occurred (or when that version of the data is valid as of). But it can be derived from the LSN (Log Sequence Number) that is stored in the history table. Additionally, columns can be added to the history table as needed, so a computed column on the history table may be leveraged to supplement this.

Further reading on limitations of CDC (Change Data Capture):

1. [Microsoft Books Online for CDC - Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations)

---

The only other consideration is for SQL Server 2014 (and 2016 RTM and older versions) unfortunately you need to be running [Enterprise Edition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/152814/150011) to be able to use the Change Data Capture feature.

Comment: Wow @J.D.! thanks for the awesome answer. I've never heard of Temporal tables before and quickly asked around seeing if people knew of em. Felt like just under half, did. Regardless, we on 2014 (and can't change easily) and it's not the enterprise edition. So i'm thinking we have to handle this manually (our own table with our own code to insert into the table). Thoughts? Is this possible?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yea unfortunately you're pretty limited in that older version (if you were on 2016 at least, then Standard Edition wold be all you need for CDC). In your case, yes you'd probably have to roll your own code to track this. You can use [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on the source Table to ensure the logging code runs everytime the sales status of a `Product` changes, and they'll be transactionally consistent.

Comment: Even if I had the data sitting in some table .. I'm hoping someone might be able to lend me a hand in how to use some query to do this?